# Insert multi column result into single column table

Tags: mysql, sql, split

I have a table 'movies' with three Columns: 'id', 'master_id' and 'searchMe' (simplified). I have another Table 'temp_ids' with a single column: 'id'. It is a temporary table, but I don't think that matters.

When I make a query on my table 'movies' like

```
SELECT `id`, `master_id` FROM 'movies' WHERE searchMe = '1';
```

I get a multi column result. Now I want to insert every id and every master_id into the 'temp_ids'-Table, but one at a time. So if my result is

```
id_1 | master_1
id_2 | master_2
id_3 | NULL
```

I want my temp_ids to look like

```
id_1
master_1
id_2
master_2
id_3
```

So I want to convert every single column in the result into its own row. How can I do that in an elegant way?
I know I can do it in multiple queries, searching for id and master_id separatly, and I know I can solve that problem with PHP or so. But I would prefer it to solve that problem in a single mysql-query, if such a thing is possible.

I made a sqlfiddle for this:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4a7f/2

Comment: I am curious to know: why do you need to do that?

Comment: I am building a tool that needs to dereference many movies and work with that data. Several queries need to access this id_collection (which of course is simplified in this example), so I want to collect it in a separate table instead of every module creating this collection on its own. And I wanted to see if there is an elegant way to do this in a single strike and not by using the PHP-Backend. And there is :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To `SELECT` the data you can use a `UNION ALL` for this:

```
SELECT  `id`
FROM movies
WHERE searchMe = 1
union all
SELECT `master_id`
FROM movies
WHERE searchMe = 1
  and master_id is not null
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4a7f/16)

Doing it this way, you cannot distinguish between what value comes from each column, so you can always add an indicator, this will give you two columns but then you know where the data came from:

```
SELECT  `id`, 'id' type
FROM movies
WHERE searchMe = 1
union all
SELECT `master_id`, 'master'
FROM movies
WHERE searchMe = 1
  and master_id is not null
```

Then you would just use this query to `INSERT INTO temp` using this `SELECT`

Comment: UNION ALL... omg, I did not recall that. Thank you, this is exactly what I need, solved in an elegant way. :)

Comment: @EmilioJ happy to help.  While I don't fully know what you need the data in one column for, I would advise if needed using the indicator in the second query then you can tell which column the data came from. :)

Comment: No, in my particular case the indicator is not needed. I just need a collection of IDs matching specific criteria after which I can process the data further. Nevertheless, the indicator could be useful to someone else, so your answer is the preferred one ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It would be like this

```
INSERT INTO temp_ids(id)
SELECT id 
FROM
(
   SELECT id
   FROM FirstTable 
   UNION
   SELECT master AS id
   FROM SecondTable 
) t
```